# Low disk space "Filesystem root"

Tags: 11.04, filesystem, disk-usage

Running 11.04 
Low disk space warning. Results of `df`:

```
Filesystem           1K-blocks      Used Available Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda2             31381148  10417896  19390492  35% /
none                   1022392       728   1021664   1% /dev
none                   1030768         8   1030760   1% /dev/shm
none                   1030768       324   1030444   1% /var/run
none                   1030768         0   1030768   0% /var/lock
/dev/sda4            245055476  35884908 196903460  16% /home
/dev/sda1             31383196    595552  29214780   2% /media/731f2d14-635c-4ef6-a0a9-88ce11464ad9
/dev/sda5            175222776   2722340 163728140   2% /media/extended
/dev/sdc1            976760032  53394052 923365980   6% /media/FreeAgent GoFlex Drive_
```

What application can be used to free up space or move files or increase the /root filesystem, safely.

result of `df -h`:

```
Filesystem            Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda2              30G   10G   19G  35% /
none                  999M  728K  998M   1% /dev
none                 1007M  8.0K 1007M   1% /dev/shm
none                 1007M  324K 1007M   1% /var/run
none                 1007M     0 1007M   0% /var/lock
/dev/sda4             234G   35G  188G  16% /home
/dev/sda1              30G  582M   28G   2% /media/731f2d14-635c-4ef6-a0a9-88ce11464ad9
/dev/sda5             168G  2.6G  157G   2% /media/extended
/dev/sdc1             932G   51G  881G   6% /media/FreeAgent GoFlex Drive_
```

result of `df -i`:

```
Filesystem            Inodes   IUsed   IFree IUse% Mounted on
/dev/sda2            1966080  315531 1650549   17% /
none                  215307    1049  214258    1% /dev
none                  219494       3  219491    1% /dev/shm
none                  219494      68  219426    1% /var/run
none                  219494       4  219490    1% /var/lock
/dev/sda4            15335424   23088 15312336    1% /home
/dev/sda1            1966080      11 1966069    1% /media/731f2d14-635c-4ef6-a0a9-88ce11464ad9
/dev/sda5            10969088      11 10969077    1% /media/extended
/dev/sdc1            924971612 1576830 923394782    1% /media/FreeAgent GoFlex Drive_
```

[image]

This IS GROWING>>>>

Comment: Either I am blind or there is a problems with misreporting.  I don't see any reason or any place where any filesystem would be low.

Comment: @BlueXrider - please posts results using df -h as well as df -i  The -h formats the output in human readable format and -i will report on used/free Inodes.

Comment: Given the sizes of your filesystems.  What is reporting the low disk space?

Comment: I don't know what is reporting. It's a nag, pop-up like.

Comment: a little further exam revels that rsync is running and the / is growing obviously, for whatever reason, copying itself as a backup. ~killing rsync stops the increased production of used disk space.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

a little further exam revels that rsync is running and the / is growing obviously, for whatever reason, copying itself as a backup. ~killing rsync stops the increased production of used disk space.

Answer (score 3):

You're only using 35% of your root-partition, it's probably a bug that it tells you it's low on space (or it's set to 10 GiBs or something like that, since most less experienced users don't differ **/** from **/home**)

To answer the question, if you like to resize partitions, you should use `gparted`. I'm quite sure this is still available on the Ubuntu Live-CD (search for "gparted" or "[partition editor](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LiveCD)") - if you can't find it on the Ubuntu CD, try downloading the [GParted Live-CD](http://gparted.sourceforge.net/livecd.php).